# @DynamicPropertySource not being invoked (Kotlin, Spring Boot and TestContainers)

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, testcontainers

I'm trying to define a `@TestConfiguration` class that is executed once before all integration tests to run a MongoDB TestContainer in Kotlin in a Spring Boot project.

Here is the code:

```
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.TestConfiguration
import org.springframework.test.context.DynamicPropertyRegistry
import org.springframework.test.context.DynamicPropertySource
import org.testcontainers.containers.MongoDBContainer
import org.testcontainers.utility.DockerImageName


@TestConfiguration
class TestContainerMongoConfig {

  companion object {

    @JvmStatic
    private val MONGO_CONTAINER: MongoDBContainer = MongoDBContainer(DockerImageName.parse("mongo").withTag("latest")).withReuse(true)

    @JvmStatic
    @DynamicPropertySource
    private fun emulatorProperties(registry: DynamicPropertyRegistry) {
      registry.add("spring.data.mongodb.uri", MONGO_CONTAINER::getReplicaSetUrl)
    }

    init { MONGO_CONTAINER.start() }

  }

}
```

The issue seems to be that `emulatorProperties` method is not being called.
The regular flow should be that the container is started and then the properties are set.
The first step happens, the second does not.

I know there is an alternative for which I can do this configuration in each functional test class but I don't like it as it adds not needed noise to the test class.

For example, with a Java project that uses Postgres I managed to make it work with the following code:

```
import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.springframework.boot.jdbc.DataSourceBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.TestConfiguration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.testcontainers.containers.PostgreSQLContainer;
import org.testcontainers.utility.DockerImageName;


@TestConfiguration
public class PostgresqlTestContainersConfig {

  static final PostgreSQLContainer POSTGRES_CONTAINER;
  private final static DockerImageName IMAGE = DockerImageName.parse("postgres").withTag("latest");

  static {
    POSTGRES_CONTAINER = new PostgreSQLContainer(IMAGE);
    POSTGRES_CONTAINER.start();
  }


  @Bean
  DataSource dataSource() {
    return DataSourceBuilder.create()
        .username(POSTGRES_CONTAINER.getUsername())
        .password(POSTGRES_CONTAINER.getPassword())
        .driverClassName(POSTGRES_CONTAINER.getDriverClassName())
        .url(POSTGRES_CONTAINER.getJdbcUrl())
        .build();
  }
}
```

I'm trying to achieve the same thing but in Kotlin and using MongoDB.

Any idea on what may be the issue causing the `@DynamicPropertySource` not being called?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`@DynamicPropertySource` is part of the Spring-Boot context lifecycle. Since you want to replicate the Java setup in a way, it is not required to use `@DynamicPropertySource`. Instead you can follow the [Singleton Container Pattern](https://www.testcontainers.org/test_framework_integration/manual_lifecycle_control/#singleton-containers), and replicate it in Kotlin as well.

Instead of setting the config on the registry, you can set them as a System property and Spring Autoconfig will pick it up:

```kotlin
    init { 
      MONGO_CONTAINER.start() 
      System.setProperty("spring.data.mongodb.uri", MONGO_CONTAINER.getReplicaSetUrl());
    }
```

Answer (score 11):

This solution works for me.

Method with `@DynamicPropertySource` is inside companion object(also added  `@JvmStatic`) and added `org.testcontainers.junit.jupiter.Testcontainers` on the test class

```java
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired
import org.springframework.boot.jdbc.DataSourceBuilder
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.TestConfiguration
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration
import org.springframework.test.context.DynamicPropertyRegistry
import org.springframework.test.context.DynamicPropertySource
import org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension
import org.testcontainers.containers.PostgreSQLContainer
import org.testcontainers.junit.jupiter.Container
import org.testcontainers.junit.jupiter.Testcontainers
import javax.sql.DataSource


@ExtendWith(SpringExtension::class)
@Testcontainers
@TestConfiguration
@ContextConfiguration(classes = [PostgresqlTestContainersConfig::class])
class PostgresqlTestContainersConfig {

    @Autowired
    var dataSource: DataSource? = null

    @Test
    internal fun name() {
        dataSource!!.connection.close()
    }

    @Bean
    fun dataSource(): DataSource? {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create()
            .username(POSTGRES_CONTAINER.getUsername())
            .password(POSTGRES_CONTAINER.getPassword())
            .driverClassName(POSTGRES_CONTAINER.getDriverClassName())
            .url(POSTGRES_CONTAINER.getJdbcUrl())
            .build()
    }

    companion object {

        @JvmStatic
        @Container
        private val POSTGRES_CONTAINER: PostgreSQLContainer<*> = PostgreSQLContainer("postgres:9.6.12")
            .withDatabaseName("integration-tests-db")
            .withUsername("sa")
            .withPassword("sa")

        @JvmStatic
        @DynamicPropertySource
        fun postgreSQLProperties(registry: DynamicPropertyRegistry) {
            registry.add("db.url") { POSTGRES_CONTAINER.jdbcUrl }
            registry.add("db.user") { POSTGRES_CONTAINER.username }
            registry.add("db.password") { POSTGRES_CONTAINER.password }
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to resolve similar problem in Groovy by:

Having static method annotated with `@DynamicPropetySource` directly in the test class (probably it would also work in superclass.

But I didn't want to copy the code into every test class that needs MongoDB.
I resolved the issue by using `ApplicationContexInitializer`

The example is written in groovy

```
class MongoTestContainer implements ApplicationContextInitializer<ConfigurableApplicationContext>{

  static final MongoDBContainer mongoDBContainer = new MongoDBContainer(DockerImageName.parse("mongo:6.0.2"))

  @Override
  void initialize(ConfigurableApplicationContext applicationContext) {
    mongoDBContainer.start()
    def testValues = TestPropertyValues.of("spring.data.mongodb.uri="+ mongoDBContainer.getReplicaSetUrl())
    testValues.applyTo(applicationContext.getEnvironment())
  }
}
```

To make it complete, in the test class, you just need to add `@ContextConfiguration(initializers = MongoTestContainer)` to activate context initializer for the test.

For this you could also create custom annotation which would combine `@DataMongoTest` with previous annotation.